# Fabric.js + IonicV3 - 'touch:gesture' event

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, fabricjs, fabricjs2

Of late, I've been trying to implement pinch and zoom in my IonicV3 App using fabric.js.

As it is given in the fabric.js documentation [here](http://fabricjs.com/touch-events), I'm not able to access evevnts and I get error in the console as :

```
[Intervention] Ignored attempt to cancel a touchmove event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted.
```

Here is my code:

```
this.canvas.on(
            'touch:gesture', function (opt) {
                opt.e.preventDefault();
                opt.e.stopPropagation();
                console.log("Fabric Canvas gesture Events----", opt);
                var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
                var pointer = this.canvas.getPointer(opt.e);
                var zoom = this.canvas.getZoom();
                zoom = zoom + delta / 200;
                if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
                if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
                this.canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: opt.e.offsetX, y: opt.e.offsetY }, zoom);
            });
```

And this is the HTML code:

```
   <ion-scroll scrollY="true" scrollX="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" >
        <div #pageContainer id="pageContainer" class="page" (click)="enableDisableObjetMove()"  >            
                    <canvas #canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
        </div>
    </ion-scroll>
```

Although in the HTML code I've also tried removing ion-scroll tag + Also tried keeping only the canvas tag.

Answer (score 0):

So after digging up why was the touchmove wasn't allowed while scrolling was in progress, I found [this](https://github.com/leonardosalles/ionic2-zoom-area/blob/master/src/zoom-area.component.ts#L88). And I clearly got the events which I wasn't able to get via `canvas.on({touch:gesture' : (event) => {'Do Anything'})`

Once I got the events all I had done was to use the below mentioned code for executing pinch and zoom in Ionic app with standard fabric.js zoom function

```
       var delta = event.e.deltaY;
        var pointer = this.canvas.getPointer(event.e);
        var zoom = this.canvas.getZoom();
        zoom = zoom + delta / 200;
        if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
        if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
        this.canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: event.e.offsetX, y: event.e.offsetY }, zoom);
        event.e.preventDefault();
        event.e.stopPropagation();
```

The code can be found from fabric.js documentation. [here](http://fabricjs.com/fabric-intro-part-5#pan_zoom)